# laravel append wheres in a loop to perform AND filtering

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to build my own dynamic filtering for my Angular App and Laravel 5.1 API using `$httpParamSerializer(params);` and Laravel `whereIns`.

My goal is to pass a set of fields and values I want to filter on and drill down the records I need.

I loop through the fields in Laravel and perform `whereIns`, then group them into an array, removing duplicates. Unfortunately, this acts more as an **OR** than an **AND**, as each `whereIn` does a new search to match.

Frontend Query:

```
        var filters = {
            'review[]' : ['no', 'yes'],
            'user_id[]' : [1]
        };
```

HTTP URL: "http://dde-api.localhost/1.0/userquestions?review%5B%5D=no&review%5B%5D=yes&user_id%5B%5D=1"

DB:

[image]

Laravel:

```
    $results = [];
    // Loop through each field (`review`, `users`, etc..), then search thru array of params
    foreach ($input as $filter_field => $filters_array) {
        if ($this->validField($table, $filter_field)) {
            $res = DB::table($table)->whereIn($filter_field, $filters_array)->get();
            if (!in_array($res, $results)) {
                array_push($results, $res);
            }
```

I need the query to work as a multiple `WHERE` clause (**AND**, not **OR**) which loops through and appends `where` clauses to each `field` ($filter_field), then searches for matching field values.

So the result should be all `yes` and `no` records for user `1`. Since user 1 doesn't have a record with `review: yes`, it uses the record from `user_id: 4`. This is bad.

How can I append multiple **WHERE** statements to one query as I loop through multiple fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Your loop like this

```
$dbTbOBJ = \DB::table("table_name")
// Loop through each field (`review`, `users`, etc..), then search thru array of params
foreach ($input as $filter_field => $filters_array) {
         $dbTbOBJ->whereIn($filter_field, $filters_array);
}
$results = $dbTbOBJ->get()
```

Comment: Rakesh what exactly is `$res` here? Also, you have omitted `$table`. How would it know which table to retrieve records from?

Comment: ok, i replicated your code as you used,  $table = Name of table that you want to use, $res is nothing its normal variable containing DB::table($table)

Comment: DB::table($table) creates a chained object. so $dbTbOBJ is a chained object and we can call allowed methods on it. If you want to check your query what is going on then make a mistake in field name. You can check constructed query.